# How to store a hidden value in a WPF combo box for use in SelectionChanged method

Tags: wpf, combobox, hidden

I have a ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox Name="Gen2Fis" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Table}"   SelectionChanged="Gen2Fis_SelectionChanged"  DisplayMemberPath="LongName">
```

The query used to fill this combobox is:

```
Select ShortName, LongName from Table;
```

Based on the item selected from this list I want call another method with the selected item, but I need to use the ShortName (that isn't displayed) instead of the LongName (which is).

How would I go about doing this?  Can I somehow hide the shortname in the list?

My method for loading the combo box:

```
public void LoadFINamesIntoList(string mainDB)
    {
        XiphosStr.ConnectString = mainDB;
        dbConnection = new MyDatabaseConnection(XiphosStr.ConnectString);
        DataSet ds = dbConnection.ExecuteQuery(Queries.getFIs);

        Gen2Fis.DataContext = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;   
    }
```

My method for the selection change:

```
private void Gen2Fis_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string gen2fi = (XiphosDB2.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem).Content.ToString();
        Gen2Str.ConnectString = gen2fi;
        DisplayGen2Users();
    }
```

gen2fi will equal the long name, but I need the short name.

Thanks for any help.

Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use SelectedValuePath from combobox and set your value path just like the display member

```
<ComboBox Name="Gen2Fis" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Table}"   SelectionChanged="Gen2Fis_SelectionChanged"  DisplayMemberPath="LongName" SelectedValuePath="ShortName">
```

and then in the selectionchanged event you would be able to use selectedValue .

```
private void Gen2Fis_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string gen2fi = ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedValue ;
        Gen2Str.ConnectString = gen2fi;
        DisplayGen2Users();
    }
```